# WPF scroolbar not working at the time of click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, treeview

I am using a treeview and assign a scroolbar for this. There is also a drag and drop feature for treeview items.

Here the code Which i have done so far..

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Height="670"
      Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="1" Background="Black" 
      Opacity="0.8">
  <TreeView Name="Servers" 
            Panel.ZIndex="1"
            Background="Transparent" Margin="2,2,2,2"       
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"                 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True"
            MouseMove="Servers_MouseMove"
            MouseDoubleClick="Servers_MouseDoubleClick">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

When i scroll through mouse then the item inside treeview is get up and down properly but on the other hand if i try to click on the scrollbar and then try to move scrollbar then this not working (i.e scrollbar frozen).
What would be the cause?

Comment: Try removing `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"` and see if this still happens

Comment: @LordWilmore , yes the problem is still same

Comment: Try to set `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled` explicitly to `"False"`. Are you doing anything special in `Servers_MouseMove`?

Comment: @haindl yes i have tried this already but couldn't help! Yes i am doing some drag and drop operations on Servers_MouseMove.